# Imported images not reflecting onto glossy objects

Tags: shaders

I have imported an image as a plane into blender and added an object with a glossy shader. for some reason the object is only reflecting the world background (gray color) and not my image. what is going on here?
I am somewhat new to blender, so if my nodes look ridiculous that is why.

links to screenshots

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-acT8LSEA8DfeA7bH2wXKJGS0KStHsE1/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zLuH07kLpPKF_5KyJnytsG9kUcOU1T0/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WfN8UiFRMixwFF-JVjN0z3Rmbagjm3_/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4zoWlXMNzNgnvlUCT-qwMwPHgeK_dyK/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-ic3xoDEp0MIs1qYDSuPCz6P-e8YpEq/view?usp=sharing

EDIT ok FFeller I tried that and it sort of reflects, but not really. I tried using a reflection plane and it didnt seem to do anything. how to get a more complete reflection?
[image: some of it does not reflect]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: You have to enable the "Screen Space Reflections" on the right side (Properties Panel).

Comment: see the edit i made to the question, i cant figure out how to post images in comments